# check file using jquery

Tags: jquery, file, upload, submit

i need to check a file while it is submitted:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").submit(function(e){
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('picture', $('#picture-field')[0].files[0]);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'checkImage.php',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.result == 0) {
            alertify.log( data.error );
        }
    }
    });
  });
});
```

In the console i can see, that there is a POST, but there is no response..could you help to figure out where the bug is? greetings

Comment: Can you open POST request in console? Do you see response there? What is the code next to the POST request in console?

Comment: sorry i looked wrong, there is no post and no request..you know what to do?